# Lets remove the tools, crash, freeze, timeout and troubleshooting tags the right way™

Tags: discussion, cleanup

Well, this is not your run off the mill tag removal request, but a petition to also close the questions with these tags. Questions tagged with such tags tend to be totally worthless, unclear and impossible to give a concise and precise answer that we could call THE answer. So, for the next 30 days, we should be pushing and closing these questions, but watch out for gems or clear questions that can be reasonably answered which only need the tag to be remove/corrected/retagged.

Here's the current status:

- [<strike>260</strike> 256 Unanswered questions with any of the 4 tags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tools+or+crash+or+troubleshooting+or+freeze+or+timeout?sort=unanswered&pageSize=15) start here! Close the ones that are crap, vote to delete the ones that are already closed, retag and fix anything else that doesn't look like crap. Please, don't duplicate these, they could be very loose duplicate but a bad duplicated still.
- [<s>990</s> 965 total questions with any of the tags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/tools+or+crash+or+troubleshooting+or+freeze+or+timeout?sort=votes&pageSize=15) (here becomes tricky since there's also good questions around that may just need a retag).

Just take one a day, fix it if it's salvageable, if not, is probably unclear (as it doesn't have enough information to diagnostic the issue) and just close it.

Don't do anything if you are unsure or ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Vote to delete the ones that are closed *and* junk. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Seth can this become a "event"?

Comment: I see some questions(such as [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/194519/i-have-lost-a-30gb-folder)) which have asked for clarification but the user hasn't responded. Should such questions be closed as "Unclear what you are asking"?

Comment: @Jobin of course.

Comment: Everyone please start going through these, I've had some from this pile I added a month ago and still only have one close vote. :(

Comment: @Seth not sure where the wording went wrong `if (crap) { close(); if (closed) { delete(); } }`

Comment: @Braiam Yes, but closed != deletion worthy necessarily. You are saying delete all the closed questions. Just because it is closed is not a good reason to delete it whatsoever. I understand *most* closed questions are deletion worthy, but that isn't a good reason to blanket them all under "deletion worthy".

Comment: @Seth if crap = true then close; if crap = true and closed = true then delete. Dunno why you insist my wording is different.

Comment: Rereading your question I can see what you mean now, the wording is just a bit confusing.

Comment: 716 unanswered now, 1735 all